# how do i get an app to read the preferences file of a different app by the same developer on the same device?

Tags: android, preferences

how do i get an app to read the preferences file of a different app by the same developer on the same device?

I make game apps and I want to be able to transfer character info from the preferences file of the free game to the paid game for the 1/4 percent or so of my free android players who are actually willing to shell out for the paid game.

also, is there a tutorial anywhere on unlocking game content through a purchase in the google play store? that would be another option.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid

You can set same android:sharedUserId.

Application with the same user ID can access each other's data

Comment: thanks, I just checked the docs on this after your quick response. it seems the solution is easier than I thought it would be. I also discovered a similar question with good answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783765/what-is-shareduserid-in-android-and-how-is-it-used

Comment: Note that this cannot, unfortunately, be added to an already published app.  For that you would need to provide an update with a different, cooperative data sharing mechanism.