# Is it possible to replace current fragment with another fragment(the other fragment is in different app)?

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I've 2 apps. First app contains an activity(MainActivity) & a fragment(FragA), second app contains another fragment(FragB). Now from first app is it possible to replace FragA with FragB. Btw I can replace fragments if all the fragments are in same app. I was wondering if it's possible.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed fragments from another application into your application. But if you own both the applications, you could consider using second application as a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to export its data. Your first application can query the second application's content provider and handle the displaying of the data on its own.

Comment: Yes I own both the applications but, I've no idea how to use content provider in this case. Will you please throw some light on this? And is this the only way to achieve what I want, is it possible to use sharedUserId to access fragment from second app example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783765/what-is-shareduserid-in-android-and-how-is-it-used  the second app is merely act as a theme. I wonder how other developers do it.