# Can an application views different application(aka in different application name) in android like webview does

Tags: android, view, cross-platform, cross-domain-policy

hi I have this crazy idea of thinking an application that can cross access from application to another.  The condition would be under same company name but just the last program package would be different.  Or is there possible to create a view to call for other application under different package name?

I wonder if this is possible.

It's just a rough idea^^;

Comment: This is already old..

Comment: You can even find it on early few pages of the android docs

Comment: Take a look at [sharedUserId][1] feature.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784342/799799