# Can we find two applications with the same Linux ID in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read in android developer site that It's possible to arrange for two apps to share the same Linux user ID, in which case they are able to access each other's files. Can anyone explain how that works practically? How system can generate same Linux ID.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to arrange for two apps to share the same Linux user ID.
check this answer for detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783966/3928104

Comment: Yes, however situations like this are handled by flagging the question for closure as a duplicate of an existing one, not by posting a link to the other answer as a new answer.