# Is it possible to share Android Keystore between different Android Apps signed with different signatures?

Tags: android, authentication, keychain, android-security

**Use Case:** Share credentials(example private key) stored in Android Keystore among different applications on the same device signed with different signatures.

I was able to achieve it using the following approach (but I don’t think it is the correct way of doing it):-

1. Signed the application with the same certificate.
2. I declared my applications with the same sharedUserId, like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mydomains.myapp"
    android:sharedUserId="com.mydomains.shared.user.id"
    android:sharedUserLabel="@string/appName">
```

Followed this post on StackOverflow: [How to securely share data between two or more applications in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302597/how-to-securely-share-data-between-two-or-more-applications-in-android)

Problems:-

1. sharedUserId is a deprecated property.
2. It requires the same signature for the apps.

Is there any other way in which we can share credentials stored in Android Keystore b/w apps on the same device?

PS:  In my usecase the Android Apps can belong to different organizations but can share a common SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the KeyChain API would be an appropriate implementation for this use case which can be used to share between apps.
For more details: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#WhichShouldIUse
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain

Hope this helps!