# How to crash or stop a Java library / Android service programmatically?

Tags: java, android, crash

I have a very special use case: I depend on a closed-source SDK library which works with a 3rd party Android app.

Everything works well up to a point the **3rd party service becomes totally unresponsive**: my app cannot get any data anymore, the official 3rd party app neither. The only way I could find to restore the proper execution is to **kill the 3rd party service** (Android settings → App → 3rd party app → Force stop).

I have therefore two solutions now:

1. Require **root** privileges to be able to kill the 3rd party app
2. Find a way to **programatically crash** the 3rd party service

I have tried to play with introspection and reflection to set some private fields to null in hope to trigger a NPE, but without luck. **Is there any generic way I could crash a library?** Maybe some kind of code injection via reflection?

Comment: see `Process#killProcess`

Comment: The killProcess() call is actually restricted to my app current PID. To override that restriction, root is required.

Comment: run it from the app that has the same UID then (`android:sharedUserId`)

Comment: That seemed promising, but it turns out it's restricted to [apps signed with the same certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783765/what-is-shareduserid-in-android-and-how-is-it-used#comment12454655_9783966) which is not my case :/