# Accessing parts of odex file dynamically

Tags: android, android-studio, dalvik, android-runtime

I want to access parts of the odex file of my android app. Better yet, the odex file of another application ( when it has for example configured my app permitting access to its odex file). From what I've found this far, I need to have a rooted device to access dalvic-cache. Would be grateful if you can guide me to do this with a non-rooted device. Thanks.

Comment: Non-rooted devices cannot access other Apps data, so ODEX of 3rd Apps cannot be read/opened without Root. It's a security reason.

Comment: Thanks, any possibility to access if the other app shares the same UUID? I'm new to the field, please excuse if I'm being naive :-)

Comment: You mean UID? If yes: starting from Android 6 (if I remember well) each App uses its own UID and can be read/write/executes files only in common/public folders and in its own Data and Cache folders. There isn't any way to use same UID without Rooting the Device.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783765/what-is-shareduserid-in-android-and-how-is-it-used and hope it's what you meant. Anyway, rooting isn't needed as per the answer. However, still I don't seem to have access. If you don't mind, would you be able to give me a few hints on how to access the odex file? TIA

Comment: Sharing UID works only on Apps signed with SAME signature, but I suppose you want to read ODEX file of other App ;) Read odex of those Apps requires Root because it's the only way to access their folders. I never read/parsed an odex file so I haven't any tip/trick to share with you. Sorry.

Comment: You helped a lot. Thank you so much! :)